# How do I see what requires a package using yarn?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, yarnpkg

My node app has a dependency that depends on `node-webcrypto-ossl`.

I'd like to run something like:

```
yarn what-depends node-webcrypto-ossl
```

To see the dependency chain, eg:

```
A
  B
    node-webcrypto-ossl
```

However I can't find anything to do this in the [yarn CLI docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli).

**How do I see what requires a package using yarn?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yarn added the [`yarn why`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why) command specifically to get information on why a package is imported.

For example:

```
yarn why node-webcrypto-ossl
```